# How to make a counter for healt and score in UI text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am very new to unity and I am trying to make a small game.
I have run into 3 main problems that I could use help with:

1. I want to make a label that shows my health:

What I already have:

```
    private int _healt;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _healt = 5;
    }
    public void Hurt(int damage)
    {
        _healt -= damage;
        Debug.Log("Health: " + _healt);
    }
```

I am showing it in the console but I need to show it in a label?

2. Make a score system with every second not death a point added and to display that in a label.
   What I tried: Nothing really I have no idea how to start
3. GameOver overlay with a reset button.
   What I tried:

   ```
    public bool _PlayerAlive;
    public void GameOver()
    {
        _PlayerAlive = true;
        if (_healt > 0)
        {
            _PlayerAlive = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _PlayerAlive = false;
        }
    }
    //Button RestartButton = yourObject.GetComponent<RestartButton>();
    public void RestartGame()
    {
        if (_PlayerAlive = false)
        {
            RestartButton.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            RestartButton.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
   ```

So basically the same thing as in question 1 linking the label with the code.

If you need any more information please ask.

Comment: You just need to do a little google'ing.  Unity has a little tutorial on setting up a shooter. Here is the page where they set up the Health Bar. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/survival-shooter-training-day-phases?projectId=5c514921edbc2a002069465e#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b71d

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this script, add public Text, or [serialzedField] private Text

Then inside unity, make a new UI text by right click -> UI -> Text

drag and drop this Text to the script Text field in the inspector

In the script inside Update(), write:
text.text = _healt.tostring()

this is simplest way to acieve this, but plz you need to google about unity UI elements to understand how it works.